# C Pass multiple strings and numbers as argument list

Tags: c, function, arguments

I'm wondering if it's at all posible to do.
I have a function to write a line to a log file with time and date but at the moment if I can only give it a single string and I have to use `snprintf` to create a custom string and pass it like that. This does work just fine but I would like to be able to pass all the variables I need and give it a string to log and posibly some variables.

This is the function

```
void myLog(char logLevel, char * file, int line, char * message, char append)
{
    char dateTime[22];
    time_t myTime = time(NULL);
    char * logLevelString;
    FILE * myLog;

    switch (logLevel)
    {
        case 1:
            logLevelString = "INFO";
            break;
        case 2:
            logLevelString = "WARN";
            break;
        case 3:
            logLevelString = "CRIT";
            break;
        default:
            logLevelString = "-ERR";
            break;
    }

    strftime(dateTime, 22, "%H:%M:%S - %d/%m/%Y", localtime(&myTime));

    myLog = fopen("Output.log", append ? "a" : "w");
    fprintf (myLog, "%s :: %s :: File: %s (line: %d) :: %s\n", logLevelString, dateTime, file, line, message);
    fclose(myLog);
}
```

And I call it like this: `myLog(1, __FILE__, __LINE__, "Opening & clearing log file success.", 0);`
and if I need some other variables in the string I do this: `snprintf(buffer, 100, "Running game %i / %i", i + 1, MAX_GAMES);` and then pass the buffer.

What I would like the function to do is get all of it at once and create the new string itself so I can call it like this: `myLog(1, __FILE__, __LINE__, "Running game %i / %i", i + 1, MAX_GAMES, 1);`

I've been trying a few things like using cstdarg and passing it multiple arguments but it either doesn't work or runs forever (well until it just stops the whole program). I've also found some similar things online but they either use all numbers or strings but I need to pass it a string and then some numbers or more strings.

Is there a way to do this or should I just keep using snprintf to create to string?

Comment: Are you aware of `vprintf`? `I've been trying a few things like using cstdarg and passing it multiple arguments but it either doesn't work or runs forever` What have you tried? It's `#include <stdarg.h>` in C.

Comment: using `sprintf` is the easiest way to achieve this. Writing your own `printf`-like variadic function is *slightly* more complicated.

Comment: See my answer: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/249042/c-logging-function/249053#249053 It does something similar to what you're looking for (inc. use of `stdarg.h`)

Comment: @KamilCuk Yes, I did try the stdarg, but it runs in the same problem. I've also tried to just pass it a complete array but I could not get the numbers in there without using another function. As for vprintf, no never seen it, but I'll have a look.

Comment: `I did try the stdarg, but it runs in the same problem` What problem? How did you "use" it? It should be as simple as `fprintf(mylog, "%s :: %s..."); va_list; va_start(va, append); fvprintf(mylog, message, va); va_end(va);`

Comment: @KamilCuk It kept running indefenetly. The way I was trying to get it to work was:

`while (message)`
`snprint(mesBuf, 50, message)`

`fprintf(..., message, ...)`

I don't have the full code anymore but it did put everything in the message but didn't stop once it ran trough all arguments. Also as a quick note, the append is a 0 or 1, it is used to switch between 'a' and 'w' with `fopen`.

Comment: @CraigEstey You solution does work but it only seems to take the first string, I can' get it to get the others as well.

Comment: Hmm ... I'm not sure quite what you mean. From your func, you're having trouble getting it to do `printf`-like args (with variable number of args)? My func does that. The only difference is the `file` and `line` arguments. It would be easy to add them to the args. And, just add a 3rd `sprintf` between the 1st and 2nd. Because of the `file/line`, to simplify, I'd create a `cpp` macro to invoke it with (e.g.): `#define MYLOG(_lvl,_fmt...) myLog(_lvl,__FUNCTION__,__LINE__,_fmt)`. Then, you could do: `MYLOG(1,"Hello %s, Goodbye %s","world","yellow brick road");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `vprintf`:

```
#idef __GNUC__
// on gcc will enable warnings, just like for printf
__attribute__((__format__(__printf__, 4, 6)))
#endif
void myLog(char logLevel, const char * file, int line, const char *fmt, char append, ...) {
    // ... rest of your code here ...

    if (myLog == NULL) /* handle errors! */ abort();

    fprintf(myLog, "%s :: %s :: File: %s (line: %d) :: ", logLevelString, dateTime, file, line);
    va_list;
    va_start(va, append);
    fvprintf(myLog, fmt, va);
    va_end(va);
    fprintf(myLog, "\n");

    // ...
}
int main() { 
    myLog(1, __FILE__, __LINE__, "Normal %s %s %llu", 1, "format", "string", 1llu);
}
```

I would suggest to change the order of arguments to `char append, const char *fmt, ...)` so that printf format string is close to `...`. I would also suggest not to open the log file each time, but keep it open. And also use `localtime_r` if available to be reentrant.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. I was trying it using vprintf like KamilCuk commented before but I guess I did something wrong since my implementation of it did not work. I do have a question tough, I took your advice on where what argument is, but I don't get why I shouldn’t open / close the file. If I don't do this won't it give problems if the program closes unexpectedly?

Comment: Call `fflush()`. The problem is takes time - it's redundant. And file is closed when program is closed anyway.